# Time interval Calculation for duplicated ID's in R

Tags: r, time, intervals

I have a large dataset.

1. I want to create a column to show the number of days between the start and the end date (from the previous row) for each duplicated ID.
   For example, for R1, since it is not duplicated, I will not calculate the interval.
   For R2, first, I need to sort it in an increasing way based on the start date. Then I calculate the number of days between the second earliest start date and the end date from the previous row. Next I continue to calculate the number of days between the third earliest start date and the end date from the second earliest start date, and so on. I want to do it for any other duplicated Ids too.
2. Then I want to create a new column to calculate the number of days in the same way as part one, for duplicated ID with the same levels of event.
   I was wondering how I can do that.

---

```
ID<-c("R1","R2","R2","R3","R3","R4","R4","R4","R4","R3","R3","R3","R3","R2","R2","R2","R5","R6")
START<-c("3-4-2013","4-5-2018","4-5-2015","4-6-2011","5-5-2012","1-9-2010","23-4-1999","25-6-2011","3-6-2011","4-5-2014",
    "6-6-2016","5-7-2014","7-7-1990","3-3-1998","4-4-1990","7-8-2014","22-4-1970","23-5-1984")
End<-c("3-4-2014","4-5-2019","5-5-2015","4-6-2013","5-5-2014","1-9-2012","23-4-2010","25-6-2015","3-6-2013","6-5-2014",
    "6-8-2016","5-8-2014","7-9-1990","3-7-1998","4-9-1990","7-12-2014","22-7-1970","23-8-1984")
event<-c("a","b","b","s","s","f","f","b","b","a","a","a","s","c","c","b","m","a")
df<-data.frame(ID,START,End,event)
```

So the results would be something like this:

```
ID     START       End     event   Time1                     Time2
1  R1  3-4-2013  3-4-2014     a     NA                        NA
14 R2  3-3-1998  3-7-1998     c     NA                        NA
15 R2  4-4-1990  4-9-1990     c    (4-4-1990)-(3-7-1998)   (4-4-1990)-(3-7-1998)
3  R2  4-5-2015  5-5-2015     b    (4-5-2015)-(4-9-1990)      NA
2  R2  4-5-2018  4-5-2019     b    (4-5-2018)-(5-5-2015)   (4-5-2018)-(5-5-2015)
16 R2  7-8-2014 7-12-2014     b    (7-8-2014)-(4-5-2019)   (7-8-2014)-(4-5-2019)
10 R3  4-5-2014  6-5-2014     a     NA                        NA
4  R3  4-6-2011  4-6-2013     s    (4-6-2011)-(6-5-2014)      NA
5  R3  5-5-2012  5-5-2014     s    (5-5-2012)-(4-6-2013)   (5-5-2012)-(4-6-2013)                    
12 R3  5-7-2014  5-8-2014     a    (5-7-2014)-(5-5-2014)   (5-7-2014)-(6-5-2014)
11 R3  6-6-2016  6-8-2016     a    (6-6-2016)-(5-8-2014)   (6-6-2016)-(5-8-2014)
13 R3  7-7-1990  7-9-1990     s                            (7-7-1990)-(5-5-2014)
6  R4  1-9-2010  1-9-2012     f
7  R4 23-4-1999 23-4-2010     f
8  R4 25-6-2011 25-6-2015     b
9  R4  3-6-2011  3-6-2013     b
17 R5 22-4-1970 22-7-1970     m
18 R6 23-5-1984 23-8-1984     a
>
```

Comment: Can you show us what the expected output is supposed to look like? Are you looking to find days elapsed only when the same event happens or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is using `dplyr` package as follows (after fixing your data frame as I show below):

```
library(dplyr)
df<-data.frame(ID,START,End,event, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$START <- as.Date(df$START, format = '%d-%m-%Y')
df$End <- as.Date(df$End, format = '%d-%m-%Y')
df %>% arrange(ID, START, End) %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(laggedTimeElapsed = difftime(START, lag(End), units = 'days'))
```

Not sure exactly what you want in #2 above, but, if you are trying to create 'event duration' within a given row, you simply do the following:

```
df %>% arrange(ID, START, End) %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(laggedTimeElapsed = difftime(START, lag(End), units = 'days'), eventDuration = difftime(End, START, units = 'days'))
```

Output here:

```
Source: local data frame [18 x 6]
Groups: ID [6]

      ID      START        End event laggedTimeElapsed eventDuration
   (chr)     (date)     (date) (chr)            (dfft)        (dfft)
1     R1 2013-04-03 2014-04-03     a           NA days      365 days
2     R2 1990-04-04 1990-09-04     c           NA days      153 days
3     R2 1998-03-03 1998-07-03     c         2737 days      122 days
4     R2 2014-08-07 2014-12-07     b         5879 days      122 days
5     R2 2015-05-04 2015-05-05     b          148 days        1 days
6     R2 2018-05-04 2019-05-04     b         1095 days      365 days
7     R3 1990-07-07 1990-09-07     s           NA days       62 days
8     R3 2011-06-04 2013-06-04     s         7575 days      731 days
9     R3 2012-05-05 2014-05-05     s         -395 days      730 days
10    R3 2014-05-04 2014-05-06     a           -1 days        2 days
11    R3 2014-07-05 2014-08-05     a           60 days       31 days
12    R3 2016-06-06 2016-08-06     a          671 days       61 days
13    R4 1999-04-23 2010-04-23     f           NA days     4018 days
14    R4 2010-09-01 2012-09-01     f          131 days      731 days
15    R4 2011-06-03 2013-06-03     b         -456 days      731 days
16    R4 2011-06-25 2015-06-25     b         -709 days     1461 days
17    R5 1970-04-22 1970-07-22     m           NA days       91 days
18    R6 1984-05-23 1984-08-23     a           NA days       92 days
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I really appreciate that. When I run your solution, the Time for Duplicated R3 would be NA! How can I fix this issue? For the secend part, I want to calculate the interval among same id  with the same event. I have already added a new column to show some part of results.

Comment: So, you don't really want the time delta in days, but as a string of two dates? The NA part is natural if there are no duplicates (and therefore lagged values). Those NA's can be replaced with whatever you want, as long as the type is the same as the column.

Comment: No, I want to calculate the number of days. For better understanding of what I want, I tried to show it in that way. R3 is duplicated observation but your solution did not calculate the number of days for it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but I see that the output does show R3 correctly handled. The first row of each new ID will always be NA when you compute its lagged value since there are no lags.

Comment: I donot know why it can not calculate it for R3. Maybe library(dplyr) doesnot works properly on my computer. I donot know how to fix it! Also regarding the second part, I am not interested to calculate the number of days for each row. I need to calculate it for the same id with the same levels of event. Any way, thanks for your suggestion for the first part. it seems correctly, i need to figure out why dplyr can not work correctly.

Comment: I know the problem. There is a bug in dplyr 4.3.0. Turns out I was using a dev version I installed using devtools. Check out their github page on how to install it. After downgrading to the 4.3.0 version, I have the same exact problem.